# Buildozer fail to compile .apk because 'xrange' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, hmac, buildozer, kivymd

i've a sort of issue with python3 pip or hmac during buildozer compiling process.

The error says 'xrange is not defined', but this happen only if I compile on a previous buildozer folder (.buildozer).

If I make a clean build removing the .buildozer folder it works as expected and also the .apk works good.

I have already added 'xrange = range' in my main.py

Any help will be appreciated. Thanx in advance.

This is the complete buildozer error:

```
[INFO]:    *** PYTHON PACKAGE / PROJECT INSTALL STAGE ***
[INFO]:    The requirements (kivy-garden.qrcode, kivy-garden.xcamera, kivy-garden.zbarcam, unix-time) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
[INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build
[INFO]:    -> running python3 -m venv venv
[INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version
[INFO]:    -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip
Exception in thread background thread for pid 27840:                                                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1633, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2557, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2261, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /bin/bash -c 'source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip'

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 105, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .util.proxy import create_proxy_ssl_context
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 3, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/bitcodepro/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1231, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 688, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 208, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 598, in build_recipes
    ignore_setup_py=ignore_project_setup_py
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 772, in run_pymodules_install
    ), _env=copy.copy(base_env))
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 907, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 837, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/ciko/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /bin/bash -c 'source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip'

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 105, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .util.proxy import create_proxy_ssl_context
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 3, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "/home/ciko/Scrivania/bitCodePro-App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/bitcodepro/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

Edit:

The issue is with hmac because it's made for python2.
The problem is in hmac.py at lines 8 and 9:

```
trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
                                             ^
trans_36 = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x36) for x in xrange(256)])
                                             ^
```

in python3 'xrange' has been removed and replaced by 'range'. So i'm trying to add 'xrange = range' in my main.py but it works only with buildozer clean build process and not if .buildozer folder is already present, even if I build a new .apk, it works on the clean build but fails during the 2nd build.

Surfing the net i founded a different way to solve the issue by downloading 'future' package via pip and adding the following line to the main.py

```
from past.builtins import xrange
```

but as i said, it works on clean build and fails during the following one.

My target is to not make a clean build every time because the process is too long. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

### I have the solution!

1. Remove 'hmac' from buildozer.spec requirements;
2. Download official python3.7 hmac.py from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hmac.html)
3. Put the hmac.py into your buildozer folder maybe in a dedicated subfolder called i.e. 'my_pkgs' and import it directly from your main.py in this way:

```py
    from my_pkgs import hmac
```

It works perfectly during the first clean build and also for all other builds released with the same .buildozer folder.
Exactly what i'm searching for.

***[SOLVED]** by me!*